# What does due in mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

What does `due in` mean in the following sentence .

> The evolution of intelligence among early large mammals of the
>   grasslands was **due in** great measure to the interaction between two
>   ecologically synchronized groups of these animals, the hunting
>   carnivores and the herbivores that they hunted.

Comment: *X is **due to** Y* often means *X is **caused by** Y*.

Answer (score 2):

It is not "due in", but "due to". The "in" is part of a separate phrase; you should parse it like this:

> ... was due, in great measure, to...